# Android WebView app crashing in emulator: null Application Context?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm developing a very simple Android app on a Mac in AndroidStudio and I've created an AVD based on the Nexus S. The app compiles with no issues, the emulator launches and then I get errors in logcat and the app crashes.  In the emulator, an error dialog displays with the message "Unfortunately App has stopped"

Here's the logcat output (error level):

```
10-01 13:59:27.813  14114-14114/com.company.app E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
10-01 13:59:27.832  14114-14114/com.company.app E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-01 13:59:27.832  14114-14114/com.company.app E/libEGL﹕ validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-01 13:59:27.832  14114-14114/com.company.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
10-01 13:59:27.832  14114-14114/com.company.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
10-01 13:59:27.832  14114-14114/com.company.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
10-01 13:59:27.854  14114-14114/com.company.app E/DataReductionProxySettingListener﹕ No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
10-01 13:59:28.530  14114-14165/com.company.app A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
10-01 13:59:28.530  14114-14165/com.company.app A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 14165 (GpuThread)
```

I'm assuming that the first error related to ApplicationContext is the cause of the other errors, but I'm not sure about that.  I've tried about 10 different methods for setting context, but the ApplicationContext error persists.

My main questions:  Is the ApplicationContext error the root cause of the crash? If not, what is?  What might I try to fix it?

Here's the complete application code for reference:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.app" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.company.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String appUrl = "http://company.com/mobile/index.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl(appUrl);
    }
}
```

MyWebViewClient.java

```
package com.company.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("company.com")) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` out of and above `<application>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @ozbek.  That was part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here's the logcat output

That is not [a Java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), and therefore is not what you're looking for.

> I'm assuming that the first error related to ApplicationContext is the cause of the other errors, but I'm not sure about that

That is some spurious message that you will see, even from apps that run fine.

> If not, what is?

As ozbek notes, [your `<uses-permission>` element needs to be moved outside of `<application>` and made a direct child of `<manifest>`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html). Your Java stack trace should mention a missing `INTERNET` permission.

It is possible that there are other problems, but that's definitely one.

Comment: Thanks.  The manifest change was one part of the solution, after that fix the app actually launched and then crashed as opposed to crashing before launch.  The other piece was updating the AVD to use native GPU.  Appreciate the help.  An you're right...the logcat message about null ApplicationContext was irrelevant.

Comment: "The other piece was updating the AVD to use native GPU."
Thanks! This was helped me.

Comment: `<uses-permission>` How could I forget it