# Android webview within application not loading

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

The intent of this is to have a webpage firing *within* the app itself. The app runs without glitches, but the webpage is never seen. The .xml contains the webpage and a list beneath it.

The .xml file reads as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity in the .java reads as

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView myWebView = new WebView(this);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Other AWS gibberish
}
```

I can get the webpage to fire as an separate application, but this is not what I want.

```
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://google.ca");
```

Edit: I have already added the internet permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Some references I have been using [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542982/android-webview-stay-in-app), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378800/clicking-urls-opens-default-browser), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746409/android-webview-launches-browser-when-calling-loadurl) and [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) without success

Edit 2: Going through the device debug files and the following are being logged

```
10-18 22:07:59.296 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 53.0.2785.124 (code 278512400)
10-18 22:07:59.306 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: SBServiceAPI: getService class android.os.ServiceManager
10-18 22:07:59.306 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 22:07:59.306 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
10-18 22:07:59.306 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-46729-141117018: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
10-18 22:07:59.306 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-18 22:07:59.336 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
10-18 22:07:59.336 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
10-18 22:07:59.336 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.ServiceWorkerControllerAdapter>
10-18 22:07:59.336 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
10-18 22:07:59.346 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.TokenBindingManagerAdapter>
10-18 22:07:59.366 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 6 ms (timestamps 655-661)
10-18 22:07:59.366 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.124", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.124"
10-18 22:07:59.376 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080ad1 (t=7 e=2769) (error -75)
10-18 22:07:59.386 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "53.0.2785.124", actual native library version number "53.0.2785.124"
10-18 22:07:59.396 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(151)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
10-18 22:07:59.436 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
10-18 22:07:59.606 7717-7826/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/DefaultDeliveryClient: Successful submission of 4 events
10-18 22:07:59.646 7717-7843/com.amazon.mysampleapp W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
10-18 22:07:59.686 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
10-18 22:07:59.696 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$WebResourceErrorImpl>
10-18 22:07:59.736 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/ConnectivityManager: CallingUid : 10097, CallingPid : 7717
10-18 22:07:59.736 7717-7854/com.amazon.mysampleapp D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: CM callback handler got msg 524290
10-18 22:07:59.766 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
10-18 22:07:59.766 7717-7717/com.amazon.mysampleapp I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.chromium.content.browser.FloatingWebActionModeCallback>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3815855/5241603

Comment: I tried loading a website which still uses http and not https with the same result, so I'm not sure if this is the reason

Comment: INTERNET permission?

Comment: Just edited the question, internet permission is set in the manifest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of instantiating a new Webview at `onCreate` I think you may need to use the one specified in your layout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.NAME_OF_THE_XML_FILE); // change here to match the name of your xml file


    // WebView myWebView = new WebView(this); instead of this, try this one below:
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Other AWS gibberish
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific import to go with this? There is a "View cannot be converted to WebView" error on gradle compile

Comment: Sorry, it was missing a cast in my solution. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Afraid not. There is a fatal error on a null object, first on the setJavaScriptEnabled() and once that is removed the fatal error moves to setWebViewClient(). 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)' on a null object reference

Comment: You also need to explicitly set the layout file your activity is rendering to match the xml described in your question. Please check again my edited answer.

Comment: Still crashing. Thank you for holding my hand through this painful experience

Comment: Sigh, I think this is turning into a hardware issue - validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY). Thank you for helping

Comment: But is it the same crash that is happening (NullPointerException)? If that's the case, two things could be the problem: either the .xml file name is incorrect or the `WebView` specified in the layout file doesn't have the `android:id="@+id/webview"` property, which is the identifier used by the Activity to find the WebView reference

Comment: It is not crashing anymore. It is simply back to loading a blank webview page

Comment: Don't know if you are testing only in the emulator, but i would suggest you test on a real Android device to check if the error still occurs. Found on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897280/android-webview-app-crashing-in-emulator-null-application-context that the problem could be related to the emulator configuration.

Comment: I am using a real android device to test